# как сбросить <input type = «file»>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сбросить кастомный инпут файл, подскажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать?

```js
document.querySelector("#file-upload").onchange = function(){
  document.querySelector("#file-name").textContent = this.files[0].name;
}
```

```css
.custom-file-upload {
  display: none;
}

.download{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="upload_cont_img" class="custom-file-upload" />
  <label id="file-name" class="input"></label>
  <label for="file-upload" class="download">Загрузить</label>
  <button type="reset" class="button-reset">сбросить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("#file-upload").onchange = function(){
  document.querySelector("#file-name").textContent = this.files[0].name;
}
document.querySelector(".button-reset").onclick = function(){
  document.querySelector("#file-name").textContent = ''; 
}
```

```css
.custom-file-upload {
  display1: none;
}

.download{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="upload_cont_img" class="custom-file-upload" />
  <label id="file-name" class="input"></label>
  <label for="file-upload" class="download">Загрузить</label>
  <button type="reset" class="button-reset">сбросить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!